# Geodesics of bounded length on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Does there exist a compact Riemannan manifold $M^n$ and an $L > 0$ such that the number of homotopy classes of simple closed curves $\gamma$ on $M^n$ whose shortest representatives have length at most $L$ is infinite?  For surfaces ($n=2$) with constant curvature metrics, this is impossible.  Thanks!

Comment: There is no canonical geodesic representative of a homotopy class of curves in a Riemannian manifold in general (there is one if the curvature is negative). Moreover the notion of homotopy class of *simple* closed curves does not make sense in dimension larger than 2.

Comment: I really meant shortest representative.  I changed the question to reflect that.  And I put simple in there because I'm also interested in other metrics on surfaces -- in higher dimensions, the condition is vacuous. 

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This cardinality is always finite, for any compact locally simply connected metric space. If there were infinitely many non-homotopic curves of length $\le L$, they would have a converging subsequence (by Arzela-Ascoli). In a locally simply connected space, any two sufficiently close curves are homotopic, so curves in the sequence are eventually homotopic to their limit, a contradiction.

Comment: +1 @Sergei.  That's very elegant.